# Socket.io with Adonis.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, adonis.js

I am using Adonis 4.1.0 and `Adonis-websocket` is only been available for `v3`. Can anyone tell me workaround for using `socket.io` with Adonis 4.1.0?

Answer (score 2):

apparently they have been working on this not long ago, it was based on `socket.io` but because of some issues like memory leaks and others, they decided to use `websockets` directly instead, check these discussions :
https://github.com/adonisjs/discussion/issues/51 
https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/integrating-socket-io-with-adonis-4/519

have you tried using `socket.io` without relying on `Adonis` ? , 
something like :

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

But you should be able to do this with `Adonis` by now according to : https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-websocket-protocol

Example :

```
const filereader = require('simple-filereader')
const msgpack = require('msgpack-lite')
const packets = require('@adonisjs/websocket-packets')

const client = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/adonis-ws')

client.onopen = function () {
  // TCP connection created
}

client.onerror = function () {
  // TCP connection error
}

client.onmessage = function (message) {
  filereader(message, function (error, payload) {
    const packet = msgpack.decode(payload)
    handlePacket(packet)
  })
}

function handlePacket (packet) {
  if (packets.isOpenPacket(packet)) {
    console.log('Server ack connection. Make channel subscriptions now')
  }

  if (packets.isJoinAck(packet)) {
    console.log('subscription created for %s', packet.d.topic)
  }
}
```

check this for broadcast examples using `WS` : https://github.com/websockets/ws#broadcast-example

Comment: yeah i tried to do according to Socket.io framework. But the issues I've been getting is I cannot emit a message when a record is inserted in Database which I think is given default in Sails.js or Adonis 3.2 version

Comment: and thank you so much for the reply. the community for adonis js is so small, though the framework is very smooth.

Comment: you're welcome :) , i don't know how you're trying to do it but you should do a `Broadcast` in the callback of the function that inserts in the database, as i mentioned above, you can use `ws` with `adonis` and these are examples on how to `broadcast` a message : https://github.com/websockets/ws#broadcast-example , i hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Create start/socket.js file and paste following code inside it.

```
const Server = use('Server')
const io = use('socket.io')(Server.getInstance())

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log(socket.id)
})
```

From Virk Himself in this forum:https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/integrating-socket-io-with-adonis-4/519

Comment: You are a life saver, as the forum is no longer available and this is nowhere to be found anymore.

Answer (score 0):

create a standalone socket io configuration file in start/socket.js

```
const io = require('socket.io')();
io.listen(3000);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log(socket.id)
})
```

to start your socket io server you can configure your server.js as below

```
new Ignitor(require('@adonisjs/fold'))
  .appRoot(__dirname)
  .preLoad('start/socket') //path of socket.js
  .fireHttpServer()
  .catch(console.error)
```

now when you start your server then it will start along with socket io